# Visual Studio 2010 UnitTestAdapter could not be loaded

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have a few dozen VS Solution, each with a a VS Test project in it that I use at work and at home. One day, the tests (in one solution) stopped running, giving me the following error when I run the tests:

> The test adapter
>   ('Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
>   required to execute this test could
>   not be loaded. Check that the test
>   adapter is installed properly. Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

It continues to run fine for everyone else on the team, and fine for me at work, but home is a failure. Also, the other solutions' test projects all run fine for me at home, it is just one of them that fails. One other tidbit, we use Moles in all of the tests (again the other moles tests work fine).

I am not seeing much about this error, except for rebuilding the test project. I would rather get to the bottom of this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Started to have problems after converting our solution from VS2008 to VS2010. For some reason when running the unit tests Visual Studio complained about Unable to find HostAdapter "Moles". Then I tried to download the latest version of Moles Framework (0.94.51023.0) and reinstall it.

Then I received the problem that is described above. All tests with the attribute HostType("Moles") failed with the following error.

The test adapter ('Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') required to execute this test could not be loaded. Check that the test adapter is installed properly. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After a lot of searching I found the reason for my problem. 
1) I opened the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt and typed fuslogvw which starts the Assembly Binding Log Viewer. 
2) I went into Settings and checked Log all binds to disk and Enable custom log path. 
3) I started one test that used to fail and the Log Viewer logged a lot of files. I opened the most recent log file and for me this one was: Microsoft.ExtendedReflection, Version=0.94.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.HTM
4) The log file describes how Visual Studio tries to find the Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.dll. But for some reason this file can't be located.

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
5) I then remembered that I had Visual Studio 2010 running when installing Moles Framework the previously. So I closed VS2010 down and re-installed it. 
6) This seemed to have done the trick

So to make a long story short. The solution for me was to close down Visual Studio and re-install Moles Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Seems like it began after I started my tests in debug mode **Debug Selection** and then interrupted execution. When I tried to run my tests after that, I got the same error.
The only thing that helped me, is to run test with **Debug Selection** again and wait till execution ends. Then tests started to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to happen when a test is interuppted (Exception thrown, etc.)

To fix, open the web.config of the site and Change this

```
  <add name="HostAdapter" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapter.Web.HttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</httpModules>
```

to this

```
</httpModules>
```

basically deleting the "hostadapter" module ... cause if the test fails unexpectedly it doesn't seem to clean itself up afterwards.